# To distribute App only to my clients and white label on already uploaded my app to Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, app-store, white-labelling

I'm iOS developer and googled my queries's answer but still i'm having some vague concept of following queries so need some expert feedback. Thanks in advance.

1. How can I distribute my app to my clients(who may have more than 1000s of users), I know i can't go with Enterprise account(as its restricted to only employee but my problem is to distribute to clients not employees), I think Apple Business manager has solution of my problem https://business.apple.com/, am I right ?
2. I already have published app on store now some of my clients want branding and then upload onto store with their name, so can Is it possible to rebrand app with same feature exist on store with different account ? AFAIK Apple isn't like it and reject app sooner or later ? If its true then what will be right solution to rebrand my iOS App.

Looking for help on these queries.

Answer (score -1):

For case 1, you can create a B2B custom app which the client can then access through Apple business manager for distribution to their users via an MDM.

For case 2, the clients would need to get their own developer program membership and make you a member of their team. You can then rebrand the app and upload a build for them to distribute under their company name.

Both of these scenarios and more are discussed in [this WWDC 2019 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/304/)